# Mac Launchpad icon jumps up

Tags: dock, launchpad

I am running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.5 on a Macbook Air.

Recently, on two occasions, I saw the Launchpad icon in the Dock jumping up and down a few times and then it stopped.

On that moment I was not active on the computer.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I just noticed the same thing happening; i think its a virus running in the background to be honest. don't know how to get rid of it :(

Answer (score 4):

Do you have automatic updates activated for apps in the Mac App Store? You can check this under System Preferences -> App Store. (Not in the non-existent Preferences in the actual App Store app, which might be confusing.)

The Launchpad icon jumps when an application has been updated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lizzan. Automatic updates is indeed activated. Regards. Peter